# Apply formula for between species comparison

Tags: r, formula

I have a data frame laid out in the follwing manner:

```
Species Trait.p  Trait.y   Trait.z
   a      20.1    7.2        14.1
   b      20.4    8.3        15.2
   b      19.2    6.8        13.9
```

I would like to apply, for each species combination, (Xa) - (Xb) where is X is the trait value and the letter is the species and Xa > Xb. I.e has to be such that the larger value of each respective species combination has to come first, calculated for every trait

Would this be a multi-step process?

An example output could be

```
Combination  Trait.p  Trait.y  Trait.z
    a/b        0.3      1.1      1.1
```

Comment: There are two b's in the species column of that data frame: how do you choose one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed you choose the largest value but David brings up a good point.  I doubt this is the best approach but I think it gives you what you're after.  Note I added a c as I'm sure your problem is a bit more complex that just a and b:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Species Trait.p  Trait.y   Trait.z
   a      20.1    7.2        14.1
   b      20.4    8.3        15.2
   b      19.2    6.8        13.9
   c      14.2    3.8        11.9", header=T)

li <- lapply(split(dat, dat$Species), function(x) apply(x[, -1], 2, max))

com <- expand.grid(names(li), names(li))
inds <- com[com[, 1] != com[, 2], ]
inds <- t(apply(inds, 1, sort))
inds <- inds[!duplicated(inds), ]

ans <- lapply(1:nrow(inds), function(i) {
    abs(li[[inds[i, 1]]]-li[[inds[i, 2]]])
})
cbind(Combination = paste(inds[, 1], inds[, 2], sep="/"), 
    as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, ans)))
```

This gives us:

```
  Combination Trait.p Trait.y Trait.z
1         a/b     0.3     1.1     1.1
2         a/c     5.9     3.4     2.2
3         b/c     6.2     4.5     3.3
```

Sorry for the lack of annotation but I'm heading to class.

Comment: My guess is that the second `"b"` was actually meant to be a `"c"`, though I'll wait for the asker to confirm.

Comment: Yes im sorry that was a typo - it was meant to be a,b,c in that column, sorry about that. Your answer looks like it will give me a great starting point - thanks